# How to prefer use of an optional part of a regular expression?

Tags: regex, sed

Is there a way of telling a regular expression (specifically `sed`) to prefer using an optional component when the input also matches without using that component?

I'm trying to extract a number from a string that may optionally be preceded by prefix. It works in the following cases:

```
echo dummy/123456/dummy | sed "s:.*/\(prefix\)\?\([0-9]\{3,\}\)/.*:\2:"
123456

echo dummy/prefix123456/dummy | sed "s:.*/\(prefix\)\?\([0-9]\{3,\}\)/.*:\2:"
123456
```

but if the string contains both a prefixed number and a "bare" number, it choses the bare number:

```
echo dummy/prefix123456/987654/dummy | sed "s:.*/\(prefix\)\?\([0-9]\{3,\}\)/.*:\2:"
987654
```

Is there a way of forcing `sed` to prefer the match including the prefix (`123456`)? All search results I've found talk of greedy/lazy options, which – as far as I can tell – don't apply here.

**Clarifications**

- The `dummy` portions in the examples above may contain slashes.
- The bit I'm interested in is *either* the first slash-delimited run of three or more digits (`.../123456/...`) *or* the first slash-delimited run of 3+ digits with a prefix (`.../prefix123456/...`), whichever occurs first.

Comment: If there is an input `dummy/123456/6789/98765/1234dummy` what do you want to match?

Comment: @anubhava I've not seen any "real world" examples like that, but were something similar to occur, I think it would be the `123456`.

Comment: Hmm in that case only `perl` solution would give `123456` for `dummy/123456/6789/98765/1234dummy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this `sed` command:

```bash
sed '
/.*\/prefix\([0-9]\{3,\}\)\/.*/{
    s//\1/
    b
}
s/.*\/\([0-9]\{3,\}\)\/.*/\1/
' file
```

which will print out

```
123456
123456
123456
123456
```

where the content of `file` is

```
dummy/123456/dummy
dummy/prefix123456/dummy
dummy/prefix123456/987654/dummy
dummy/987654/prefix123456/dummy
```

Comment: ++ This is good, though it requires 2 substitutions

Comment: Given the nature of the `dummy` parts, this two-stage process seems to be what is required.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` BRE or ERE doesn't have a way to use lazy quantifier in starting `.*?`.

However, based on your use-cases, you may use this `sed`:

```bash
sed -E 's~[^/]*/(prefix){0,1}([0-9]{3,})/.*~\2~' file

123456
123456
123456
```

where input is:

```bash
cat file

dummy/123456/dummy
dummy/prefix123456/dummy
dummy/prefix123456/987654/dummy
```

Here we are using negated character class (bracket expression) `[^/]*` instead of `.*` to allow pattern to match 0 or more of any char that is not a `/`.

---

If you can consider `perl` then `.*?` with a negative lookahead will work for you:

```bash
perl -pe 's~^.*?/(?:prefix)?(\d{3,})(?!.*prefix\d{3}).*~$1~' file
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJs7oh/1)

Comment: This won't work with the line `dummy/987654/prefix123456/dummy`

Comment: That's right `sed` solution won't work for those cases but my updated `perl` would work

Comment: @anubhava Unfortunately, the `dummy` part may contain slashes (I've clarified this in an edit: sorry for not making it clear originally).

Comment: Yes that's why I suggested a `perl` solution as well that does it in a single replacement.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk` you could try following code. Written and tested with shown samples only.

```bash
awk 'match($0,/\/(prefix){0,1}([0-9]+)/,arr){print arr[2]}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using GNU `awk`'s `match` function. In it using regex `(prefix){0,1}([0-9]+)` which is having 2 capturing groups and its matched values are getting stored into array named `arr` and if condition is fine then printing 2nd element of that array.